# Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library (Mac)?

Tags: eclipse, macos

I'm trying to use a JRE bundled Eclipse version under Mac.
Interestingly, it works when I run
`./Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOSX/eclipse`

So eclipse is able to find and use the bundled JRE.´

It is a Eclipse Neon, where the Info.plist file contains the -vm argument pointing to `../../../jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib`.

However, running via `open ./Eclipse.app` (or using Finder) I get "Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library".

I do not have any JRE installed on the system.
Sadly, using open I cannot get stderr or something as far as I know.

Comment: What bundled JRE is this? I am not aware of any official Eclipse download with a bundled JRE. The normal procedure on the Mac is to install a JDK (not a JRE) from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: Sadly it's not an official eclipse distribution (AFAIK there is not official Eclipse bundled with JRE or JDK; otherwise I could gather information from it)

Comment: Well I strongly suggest you install the Oracle Java 8 JDK from the official site and then install one of the official Eclipse Neon downloads from the Eclipse site. This works without problems for me.

Comment: I could do that, but I want to have it portable, since I can put it on an USB stick and use it from a Mac which does not have Java installed.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I have the very same problem, but for an RCP application I have developed. For practical reasons I want to bundle the the JRE with the application. 
Does anybody know the difference (internally) between running the .app file and running the executable? Is there any way to get more verbose output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the -vm parameter in the .plist file had the wrong format. The parameter name and the value need to be in separate string elements:

```
<key>Eclipse</key>
<array>
    <string>-vm</string>
    <string>../../../jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib</string>
</array>
```

As to why it worked when starting the executable file:
Apparently the vm parameter is read from the .plist file when running the .app file, but from the eclipse.ini file when starting the executable directly.